# Получение динамического id в express

Tags: node.js

Добрый день!
Большая просьба помочь, сделал регистрацию, что бы при входе на главную страницу у пользователя были уникальные id, выглядит вот так: [http://localhost:7778/mainPage?id=idПользователя](http://localhost:7778/mainPage?id=id%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F). 
Проблема в следующем: не могу через express обратиться к странице с уникальным id, написал следующим образом:

```
app.get("/mainPage:id", function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params);
});
```

Но страница не отзывается и не выводит ничего в консоль. Я уверен, что я что-то пропустил, или вообще не сделал. Только неделю как изучаю node, express.
Надеюсь понятно объяснил, заранее большое спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Либо

[http://localhost:7778/mainPage/idПользователя](http://localhost:7778/mainPage/id%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F)
и

```
app.get("/mainPage/:id", function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params.id);
});
```

Либо
[http://localhost:7778/mainPage?id=idПользователя](http://localhost:7778/mainPage?id=id%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F) и

```
app.get("/mainPage", function (req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.query.id);
});
```

И не забудьте подключить [body-parser](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser)